# How do i Gzip responses using require.js in node.js

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, requirejs

I have, a regular express.js app, i am using

```
app.use(express.compress())
```

to compress gzip responses, now when i go to regular view pages in node.js, they all show up as being served using gzip in browser. But when i get to the page with the backbone app, the responses are not gzipped. Maybe i am missing something here. This is what my app.coffee looks like:

```
app = express()
app.use(express.compress())

app.set "port", process.env.PORT or 3000
app.set "views", __dirname + "/views"
app.set "view engine", "jade"
app.engine 'hamlc', require('haml-coffee').__express

app.use express.favicon()
app.use express.logger("dev")
app.use express.bodyParser()
app.use express.methodOverride()
app.use express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public"))
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/dist'));
app.use('/docs', express.static(__dirname + '/docs'));
app.use('/tmp', express.static(__dirname + '/tmp'));

app.use require('connect-assets')()
```

Which to me seems like a regular app.coffee. and this is how require.js loads up in the view.

```
- if(settings.env == 'production')
  script(type='text/javascript', data-main='/dist/js/main.js',       src='javascripts/backbone/marionette/require.js')
- else
  script(type='text/javascript', data-main='javascripts/backbone/main.js', src='javascripts/backbone/marionette/require.js')
```

The backbone app loads up fine, the only issue is , its NOT gzipped. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you verify it is not gzipped?

Comment: Try explicitly adding `app.use(app.router);` before `express.compress`

Comment: We load the router last. We add general middleware in this order: compress, static, bodyParser, cookieParser, session, methorOverride, and router. We have a couple other middleware we built that are in between, but they don't interfere with the stock middleware I just listed.

Answer (score 1):

At ZingProject.com, we use Express 3.2.6 and like you, we ensure gzip compressing like this:

```
app.use(express.compress());
```

Transfer sizes verified in Chrome were 20%-80% smaller with by just adding this line so we know that works.

How are you verifying that the transfers are NOT compressing? In Chrome inspector, on the network tab you will see a transfer size with two numbers. One is the amount of network data transferred, and the other is the actual uncompressed size of the file. If the numbers are different, your compression is working correctly. If the numbers are the same, something is indeed off. Firebug only shows you the network transfer size, so you will have to turn compression on and off, and compare the sizes of transfers with each if you are using Firefox.

Comment: Its outdated, actual info is here: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect#middleware